# Tmux session does not always open with expected mount bindings

Tags: tmux, mount, unshare

I want to run unshare, mount a few directories, and run a tmux session in the new mount namespace. Here is my setup

```
$ cat run
#!/bin/bash
mount --bind ~/a ~/b
tmux
$ unshare -r --mount ~/run
```

When I run this command, I get dropped into the tmux session but without the binding. What is more strange to me is that if I rerun the mount command in the tmux session and exit, the next time I run `unshare -r --mount ~/run` the binding is there!
I could get consistent behavior by always running the mount command in the tmux session but I would like to understand why the behavior depends on if the binding existed in a previous session.

Replacing `tmux` with `/bin/bash` to poke at the mounted directory shows that the binding always happens, as expected. Once running the mount command in tmux, all subsequent runs have the binding until I move `~/a`. Then the problem is back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now unable to reproduce my own problem. I suspect the solution was to power cycle. I do not think I had done so between installing tmux and running into this issue, so that may have been the root cause.